# (Python) - Need some help involving the CSV writer

Tags: python, csv

My group and I are building a program to record cash/credit expenses and writing them to a CSV file. With our code, we're wanting to be able to convey the type of expense being made (1 = Entertainment, 2 = Food/Groceries, etc) and how much the expense was. The code works great when the expense amount is in the single digits, such as [1][5], meaning it'd be a $5 Entertainment expense. However, when we spend, let's say $55 dollars, it further separates it as [1][5][5] when we open the CSV file. Is there a way where we can alter how how we separate our values in the CSV file, such as it writing [1][55] to mean $55 in Entertainment expenses?

The relevant code snippet is below for reference. Thank you in advance for your help. Oh, and we're using Python 2.7 for our programming.

---

```
        if expense_type == '1':
            print 'Enter Expense Type and Amount\n' \
                  '1. Entertainment\n' \
                  '2. Food/Groceries\n' \
                  '3. Gas/Maintenance/Travel\n' \
                  '4. School/Work\n' \
                  '5. Misc.\n'

            while True:
                exp_type = raw_input('Enter Expense Type Option Number\n')
                exp_amt = raw_input('Enter Expense Amount')
                cash_exp_log[exp_type] = exp_amt

                print 'Would You Like To Record Another Cash Expense?'
                go_again = raw_input('Y/N\n')

                if go_again == 'N':
                    break


            with open('cash_exp.csv', 'a+') as csvfile:
                writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
                for key, value in cash_exp_log.items():
                    writer.writerow((key + value))
            break
```

---

Comment: There's no csv reading code?

Comment: I believe the line: "with open('cash_exp.csv', 'a+') as csvfile:" includes reading the code as well as allowing us to append to it. Correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Yes, it allows you to read *and* write but in the example you're only writing and the reading of the file could have been relevant as well. Anyway, it seems you got an answer that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the line `writer.writerow((key + value))`. The `writerow()` method takes a Python [iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#iterable), which is roughly "anything that you can give to a for loop". `writerow()` takes the iterable, iterates it, and puts each element it gets from iteration into a cell in the CSV -- it puts commas between them (and does some other formatting).

The value that you're passing in is a string (the result of concatenating `key` and `value`), and when you iterate a string, you get each character:

```
>>> for letter in "hello":
...     print letter
...
h
e
l
l
o
```

Thus, when the combined string is only 2 characters long -- because the expense code is always 1 digit, and the expense amount is also 1 digit -- you get 2 columns; but if the expense amount is 2 (or more) digits, you'll get additional columns.

Judging from the parentheses you've wrapped around the expression `key + value`, I'm guessing what you meant to do is to pass a tuple to `writerow()`. To do that, you want to use `(key, value)` -- the comma makes it a tuple.

Comment: I changed (key + value) to (key, value) and as far as I can see, it's working as intended now. Thank you so much for the information about the concatenation resulting in a string and not a tuple, I'll pass it along to my group.